# GitLab continuous integration to run jobs in several branches

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html) file contains the following job:

```
job1:
  script: 
    - pwd
  only: 
    - master
```

Using [`only`](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except) I make this dummy job `job1` run the command `pwd` only when it gets a push into the branch `master`. From the docs:

> only and except are two parameters that set a refs policy to limit
>   when jobs are built:
>
> *only* defines the names of branches and tags for which the job will be built.

Now I would like to run this on multiple tags, so following the docs:

> *only* and *except* allow the use of regular expressions.

I tried to say:

```
job1:
  script: 
    - pwd
  only: 
    - (master|my_test_branch)
```

But it does not work at all: neither in `master` nor in `my_test_branch`. What is wrong with the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just to use multiple values (more readable in my opinion):

```
only:
    - master
    - my_test_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any documentation about it, but apparently regular expressions in `.gitlab-ci.yml` need to be enclosed in `/ /`. Thus, `/(master|my_test_branch)/` works.

All together:

```
job1:
  script: 
    - pwd
  only: 
    - /(master|my_test_branch)/
```